# How to style AlertDialog Actions in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, android-alertdialog

I use this method to show a AlertDialog:

```
_onSubmit(message) {
    if (message.isNotEmpty) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Center(child: Text('Alert')),
            content: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children : <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    message,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,

                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Cancel'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }),
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Ok'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _inputTextController.clear();
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  })
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Everything is working but the buttons are aligned in right as shown on picture below:

[image]

I want to style some how the buttons, for example one on start other on end.
I searched in docs but only found how to make them "Stacked full-width buttons".
Any ideas how to style the buttons?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Update 2022/10/22**

[Flutter 2.5](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-2.5.0) introduced the [actionsAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog/actionsAlignment.html) property:

```
AlertDialog(
  title: ..
  actions: ..
  actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end
),
```

**Customize widget**

Edit the the widget itself: Under the `AlertDialog` there is a [ButtonBar widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ButtonBar-class.html) where you can use `alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to align the buttons correctly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50966702/5237072) for an example of a custom AlertDialog widget.

**Own button row**

You could also remove the buttons under `actions` and add an own custom `Row` with [RaisedButtons](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html) in it, somehow like this:

```
Row (
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(), // button 1
        RaisedButton(), // button 2
    ]
)
```

In your case you could add a [Column](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) around the Row in `content` and in there add your existing Row and the modified one you created from the above example.

Comment: no need to use row, just use the `actionsAlignment: spaceBetween`

Answer (score 26):

Move buttons to content is a good solution.

```
showDialog(
              context: context,
              barrierDismissible: false,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Center(child: Text('Alert')),
                  content: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          "message",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton(
                              child: Text('Yes'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              }),
                          FlatButton(
                              child: Text('No'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              })
                        ])
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              });
```

Answer (score 10):

Changing the theme is a good option.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
      buttonBarTheme: ButtonBarThemeData(
    alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  )),
  ...
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't add button in **actions** of AlertDialog. As you can see.

```
_onSubmit(message) {
    if (message.isNotEmpty) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Center(child: Text('Alert')),
            content: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children : <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    message,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,

                    ),
                  ),
                ),

         FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Cancel'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }),
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Ok'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _inputTextController.clear();
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  })
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

I use this method to align buttons in actions of **AlertDialog**.

How this works::

The SizedBox takes the full width of the alertdialog using its context(In the statement MediaQuery.of(***context***).size.width. After that,  a row is used which places space between its children in the main axis(mainAxisAlignment => the x-axis for a row).

**AlertDialog style:**

```
AlertDialog(
        title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text('Title'),
              CloseButton(
                  color: Color(0xFFD5D3D3),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  })
            ]),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(child: Text("Boby")),
        actions: [
          SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 25.0,
                        height: 25.0,
                        child: OutlineButton(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                            child: new Text("Save"),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                            onPressed: () {})),
                    SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                    ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 25.0,
                        height: 25.0,
                        child: OutlineButton(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26),
                            textColor: Colors.blue,
                            child: new Text("Close"),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                            onPressed: () {}))
                  ]))
        ]);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the straightforward answer for your problem:
Just use actionsAlignment property of AlertDialog class in flutter. Like so

```
AlertDialog(
  actions: ...,
  actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [RFlutter Alert](https://github.com/RatelHub/rflutter_alert) library for that. It is easily customizable and easy-to-use. Its default style includes rounded corners and you can add buttons as much as you want.

Alert Style:

```
var alertStyle = AlertStyle(
    animationType: AnimationType.fromTop,
    isCloseButton: false,
    isOverlayTapDismiss: false,
    descStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    alertBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
    side: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.grey,
    ),
    ),
    titleStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.red,
    ),
);
```

And assing your AlertStyle object to Alert's style field.

```
Alert(
    context: context,
    style: alertStyle,
    type: AlertType.info,
    title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
    desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
    buttons: [
    DialogButton(
        child: Text(
        "COOL",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 179, 134, 1.0),
        radius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
    ),
    ],
).show();
```

*I'm one of developer of RFlutter Alert.