# Aligning alert dialog button bar widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter, so I'm trying to create a widget that shows an alert dialog. In the content of alert dialog I got SingleChildScrollView and in, so called, button bar I have a text, checkbox and a button, which I want to align(put checkbox with text on the left side, the button on the right side), but I don't know how. Tried expanded and flexible, also tried to insert row with mainAxisAlignment set to spaceEvenly, not working, could someone please help me?

Here is the code:

```
class TermsAndConditionsAlertDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  TermsAndConditionsAlertDialogState createState() {
    return new TermsAndConditionsAlertDialogState();
  }
}

class TermsAndConditionsAlertDialogState
    extends State<TermsAndConditionsAlertDialog> {
  static bool _isChecked = false;

  //TODO get the terms and conditions message
  static final String _TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS_MESSAGE =
      'blablabla this is a terms and conditions message and a blablababl and a bla bla and a aaaaaaaaaaaa bla';
  static final String _DIALOG_TITLE = 'Terms and Conditions';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text(_DIALOG_TITLE),
      content: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Text(
          _TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS_MESSAGE,
          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new Text('Accept'),
        new Checkbox(
//          title: Text('Accept'),

          value: _isChecked,
          onChanged: (bool newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _isChecked = newValue;
            });
          },
        ),
        new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _printDialogResult();
              _closeDialog();
              //TODO add a method to move on with an app

            },
            child: new Text(
              'Start',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _printDialogResult() {
    //simply prints the result in console
    print('You selected 1');
  }

  void _closeDialog() {
    if (_isChecked) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
}[FL][1]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style AlertDialog Actions in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235014/how-to-style-alertdialog-actions-in-flutter)

Comment: I think you can use simpledialog instead of alert, with simple dialog you can custom the widget whatever you want

Comment: May be a duplicate, but, actually I did not find any of the comments working and any of clarifications enough, so I created this one.. Will try to run a testcase with SimpleDialog, thanks))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the **content** property to place your widgets because the **actions** will actually be wrapped in a `ButtonBar` and placed on the bottom right.

So a solution may be split the content of the dialog with a `Column` letting the `SingleChildScrollView` to expand to fill the viewport and placing a `Row` with your desired widgets on the bottom with the `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,`. Since you also want to group the `Text` and `CheckBox`, another `Row` will do the job to gather both next to each other.

I've edited your example so you can copy/paste and try/tweak it yourself. This will produce the result below.

[image: example]

```
class TermsAndConditionsAlertDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  TermsAndConditionsAlertDialogState createState() {
    return new TermsAndConditionsAlertDialogState();
  }
}

class TermsAndConditionsAlertDialogState extends State<TermsAndConditionsAlertDialog> {
  static bool _isChecked = false;

  static final String _TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS_MESSAGE =
      'blablabla this is a terms and conditions message and a blablababl and a bla bla and a aaaaaaaaaaaa bla';
  static final String _DIALOG_TITLE = 'Terms and Conditions';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text(_DIALOG_TITLE),
      content: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: new Text(
                _TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS_MESSAGE,
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text('Accept'),
                  new Checkbox(
                    value: _isChecked,
                    onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _isChecked = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _printDialogResult();
                    _closeDialog();
                  },
                  child: new Text(
                    'Start',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _printDialogResult() {
    print('You selected 1');
  }

  void _closeDialog() {
    if (_isChecked) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!))))) This definitely is what I was seeking for.  Yeah, in documentation says that the ButtonBar's default orientation is MainAxisAlignment.end, so there is no way this can be changed inside of the AlerDialog's children though?

Comment: Yes you can. Just change the column alignment.