# How to center AlertDialog FlatButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

How can I style the FlatButton to be aligned on center without having to create a custom AlertDialog?

```
AlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        'Alert Dialog'.toUpperCase(),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 28.0),
      ),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListBody(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Scrollable AlertDialog' * 100),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            'Accept'.toUpperCase(),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dfsk.png)

I tried removing 'actions' and adding the FlatButton inside a row in 'content', but the scroll stopped working and the content overflowed.

```
content: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Scrollable AlertDialog.' * 50),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Accept'.toUpperCase(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16.0
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Google's material design guidelines don't want you to place that in center, which is why Flutter team used `ButtonBar` for `actions` and you have no control over `ButtonBar`'s alignment inside `actions` property, so if you really want to center your single button, there are 2 simple workarounds:

1. Make changes in source code, in `dialog.dart`'s `AlertDialog`'s `build` method, you'll see a `ButtonBar`, widget, add `alignment` to it.

   ```
   ButtonBar(
     alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // add this line 
     // ...
   )
   ```
2. You can use dummy widgets like `SizedBox` and provide some width to it.

   ```
   actions: [
     SizedBox(width: space),
     FlatButton(
       onPressed: () {},
       child: Text('Button'),
     ),
     SizedBox(width: space),
   ]
   ```

---

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use actionsAlignment property in AlertDialog Widget.

```
AlertDialog(
  actions: ...,
  actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to play around with actionsPadding which is one of the property of AlertDialog.

```
final horizontalPadding=50;
```

horizontal padding is the one that is transparent to the left and right of the dialog.

```
actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-horizontalPadding*2),
```

Also, go through [How to style AlertDialog Actions in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235014/how-to-style-alertdialog-actions-in-flutter) . You can change and play around within the library as mentioned here. **But, this may not work for your colleagues who are sharing the git repo. They will have to update their libraries as well in their local machines.**

Answer (score 0):

```
    actions: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              //your logic
              Navigator.pop(context);
             },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('Close'),
            ),
          ),
      ),
    ],
```