# Flutter & AlertDialog : How do I align my AlertDialog to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: flutter, android-alertdialog

Flutter & AlertDialog : How do I align my AlertDialog to the bottom of the screen?
AlertDialog normally appears in the middle of the screen. How do I put it at the bottom of the screen?

```
   showDialog(
       return AlertDialog(
          content : Container()
       );
    )
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235014/how-to-style-alertdialog-actions-in-flutter

Comment: There is also a convenient way, you may use a modal Bottom Sheet instead of AlertDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use `showdialog`? To pop a section from the bottom of the screen you need to use bottom sheet behavior with the `showBottomSheet` method. Here is how to use the bottom sheet:

```
showBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context){
      return Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ListTile(title: Text('title 1'),),
            ListTile(title: Text('title 2'),),
            ListTile(title: Text('title 3'),),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
```

I recommend you to use the [flutter_modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) plugin. This plugin provides lots of bottom sheet behavior for both Material and Cupertino design. For example :

After installing the plugin you can use it like this for material design:

```
showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context, scrollController) => Container(),
)
```

Or for ios Cupertino design:

```
showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context, scrollController) => Container(),
)
```